# cannot get (atom) pug lint to work, is it rocket science?

Tags: pug, atom-editor

I have wasted way too much time on trying to get pug-lint to work in Atom. I cannot for the life of me figure out why it will not work. I feel like molting right now. I followed the directions on https://github.com/pugjs/pug-lint and https://atom.io/packages/linter-pug which pretty much consists of:

```
npm install -g pug-lint
apm install linter-pug
```

At some point, I got the notion that I needed to create a .pug-lintrc file except there is no place in the linter-pug settings inside of atom to point to such a file.

Does anybody know how to get this to work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you install a package using apm, restart or reload the application in order to detect and install all dependencies and changes. Also to get linter to work you need to install the target language (jade or pug). Remember to reload application after every package installation or configuration change, that's best way to keep things in line.

Comment: Yes I’ve tried so many things. Still no joy :-( My other linters work so not sure what’s up with this one.